# Remove Columns from a table that are 90% one value

Tags: r, dataframe

Example Data:

```
A<- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2)
B<- c(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J)
C<- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0)
D<- c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE)
df1<-data.frame(A,B,C,D)

df1 %>%
  select_if(
    ###column is <90% one value
  )
```

So I have a table that has a few columns that are predominantly one value--like C and D in the above example. I need to get rid of any columns that are 90% or more one unique value. How can I get rid of the columns that fit this criteria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use `select` with `where`, get the frequency count with `table`, convert to `proportions`, get the `max` value and check if it is less than `.90` to select the particular column

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>% 
    select(where(~ max(proportions(table(.))) < .90))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2), B = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"), C = c(1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), D = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```